# Image download link is not work in light box

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I am using the [light box](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) for my current project. 
I add custom custom download link inside the lightbox.
But Download doesn't work even the url is correct.
When I **righclick**> **open with new tab**, the image is downloaded.
Here's [my demo page](http://winsandymyint.com/dede/photo-gallery.html) for your reference. Please kindly check what I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have some JavaScript somewhere that has bound an event listener to the click event on anchors that is preventing the click event from bubbling up to the browser to handle the event naturally. It doesn't look like all anchors are getting this event handler, so I'd start looking in the code for the lightbox itself. I was able to turn off JavaScript with your lightbox open and click the download link and the test.zip file downloaded just fine.